# Mac Terminal: Looping & ImageMagick

Tags: macos, terminal, imagemagick

I have a several folders with images in them, something like this structure:

```
parent-folder
   01
   02
   03
```

I would like to convert them using ImageMagick. I can easily do this:

```sh
cd parent-folder/01
convert *.jpg output.pdf
```

This works perfectly, but I have more than 90 folders -- which makes this very time consuming.

Is there a way to loop through each of the folders, applying the imagemagick command to each folder?

I started approaching it this way:

```sh
cd parent-folder
for d in *; 
do convert *.jpg output.pdf; 
done
```

But I have no luck. I know the code above won't work as I'm still in the parent-folder. Any ideas the best way to approach this problem? I am also open to other solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me using the bash `find` command to find all first level directories in a folder on my Mac desktop called `testing`. Then loop over each one. The folder structure is:

```
testing
    test1
        lena.jpg
        mandril3.jpg
        zelda1.jpg
    test2
        lena.jpg
        mandril3.jpg
        zelda1.jpg
```

Here is the code:

```
cd desktop
for folder in `find "testing" -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`; do
echo "$folder"
convert ${folder}/*.jpg ${folder}/output.pdf
done

testing/test1
testing/test2
```

The resulting folder structure now shows output.pdf in each.

```
testing
    test1
        lena.jpg
        mandril3.jpg
        output.pdf
        zelda1.jpg
    test2
        lena.jpg
        mandril3.jpg
        output.pdf
        zelda1.jpg
```